# I'm following a tutorial and get an uncaught Syntax error in promise while the code in the video works just fine, Please look into it

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, syntax-error

I'm a learner on currently following a YouTube tutorial on JS, And the below code worked fine in the video, but I get an error message

**error:**
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Console log shows the line which has the code `console.log("finished!");` as the line with the error

**The JS code:**

```
const getDataFromForm = () => {
  const requestObj = {
    firstName: "Humaid",
    lastName: "Ahamed",
    categories: ["nerdy"],
  };
  return requestObj;
};

const buildRequestUrl = (requestData) => {
  `http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random?firstName=${requestData.firstName}&lastName=${requestData.lastName}&limitTo=${requestData.categories}`;
};

const requestJokeAnotherMethod = async (url) => {
  const Response = await fetch(url);
  const jsonResponse = await Response.json();
  const joke = jsonResponse.value.joke;
  postJokeToPage(joke);
};

const postJokeToPage = (joke) => {
  console.log(joke);
};

const processJokeRequest = async () => {
  const requestData = getDataFromForm();
  const requestUrl = buildRequestUrl(requestData);
  await requestJokeAnotherMethod(requestUrl);
  console.log("finished!");
};

processJokeRequest();
```

Comment: Did you do elemental debugging to see where the error occurs?  FYI, `buildlRequestUrl()` has no return value.  So, `const requestUrl = buildRequestUrl(requestData);` just gets you `undefined` and thus probably `const Response = await fetch(url);` does not get you an OK `Response` or rejects.

Comment: Thank you, I forget to add "return" before the Chuck Norris API link, I can't believe I didn't notice such a simple mistake before,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've notice that I've forgot to return the Chuck Norris API link, Now the code works like charm, Thank you for that person that pointed out my mistake

I had previously not included the `return` statement in the below function:

```
const buildRequestUrl = (requestData) => {
  return `http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random?firstName=${requestData.firstName}&lastName=${requestData.lastName}&limitTo=${requestData.categories}`;
};
```